# ChildProcess: stdin not getting read by Python readline

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, stdin, child-process

I am trying to interact with a Python script from Node via stdin/out using `child_process` like so:

```
var p = require('child_process').spawn('python', ['test_io.py']);

p.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

p.stdin.write('thing');
```

and this is the relevant Python portion:

```
import io
import sys

_input = io.open(sys.stdin.fileno())
_output = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w')

while True:
  _output.write(_input.readline())
```

However, right now it seems the Python script is not reading "thing" passed in via `stdin.write`. Shouldn't these writes be buffering? What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For my case, the solution is to **add a newline at the end (`+ '\n')`** when writing to py stdin in js. --ie:  `this.python.stdin.write(JSON.stringify({ word_toLemmatize }) + '\n');` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791601/node-js-cant-read-python-subprocess-stdout-when-it-read-from-stdin/78163024

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @lispHK01 answer You need to terminate the stdin - particularly when sending small amounts of data as it will be sitting in a buffer.

Try this:

```
var p = require('child_process').spawn('python', ['test_io.py'], { stdio: 'pipe'});

p.stdin.write('thing');
p.stdin.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var p = require('child_process').spawn('python', ['test_io.py'], { stdio: 'pipe'});
```

ChildProcess has some idiosyncracies -- from the docs for ChildProcess.stdin:

> If the child was not spawned with stdio[0] set to 'pipe', then this
>   will not be set.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin